# Linking to CSS within SharePoint Asset Library renders incorrectly

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

For some reason, when I link to CSS in SharePoint, it renders incorrectly. However, when I place the CSS directly in the page or link to it raw through BitBucket, GitHub, or via CDN, it renders the page correctly. Can SharePoint not be used to host Intranet design files like js and css?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to include the css style sheets?

Comment: I just use an @import within style tags.

Comment: when using `@import` you must use local files

Comment: @Justin: As stated in the OP, the CSS renders correctly when I use BitBucket, GitHub, and CDN-hosted files. The *only* time I experience an issue is when I host the file from within SharePoint.

Comment: By render incorrectly, do you mean the CSS is different or that the build step fails?

Comment: I mean that when the CSS is imported from a SharePoint library, the page becomes half a page with scrollbars along the top and bottom. It's bizarre. The page is then unusable/unviewable.

Comment: Given that i don't know what the specific are its hard to debug this. But I would confirm you're importing CSS and not another form. Make sure the CSS is exactly what you expect it to be, compare against the other libraries. Make sure its loading in the right order so the cascade is correct. Given the bug you're saying its likely there is some extra CSS that is getting added that you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I needed to host it from the Style Library, where no meta gets attached. Now everything is working perfectly! Thanks for everyone’s help! Hopefully if someone else comes along with the same issue, they’ll see how much thought we went through to troubleshoot it! Appreciate all the effort, everyone! :D